# React Native - OpenWeatherMap : Declaration with the same name

Tags: javascript, destructuring

**Hello everyone !**

I am a student creating a "weather" tab for a mobile application project.

I am using the OpenWheatherMap API, "One Call API" precisely  and I have a small problem.
To receive the information from the API here is what I do:

1.WeatherScreen.js

2.WeatherInfo.js
[image: WeatherScreen]

[image: WeatherInfo]

And this is the error I got (I know the meaning of it but don't know how to bypass it) :
[image: Error]

If someone can indicate me what to do it will be awesome !

Thanks in advance and good day / good night !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are destructuring `currentWeather` and you have `temp` in both `current` and `daily` and you have `icon` in both `weather` and `daily`. Destructuring is fine but you need to alias those fields so you don't end up with re-declaration of `temp` and `icon`.

Here is an example:

```
const { current: { temp: currentTemp, humidity, wind_speed }, 
  // etc.
  daily: { temp, icon },
  // etc.
}
```

This way, `temp` variable is not duplicated and will point to daily temperature and `currentTemp` will point to current temperature.

Comment: Thanks for the reply !
With your example I was able to correct those error, great !
But for some reason, it seems I can't display any fields of my "daily" ...
Anyway, your answer solved my problem, thanks !

Comment: @QuentinBlanche I'm glad it worked. You can accept the answer if it solved the problem. I'm sure there is a solution to your problem with `daily`, but is better to ask a different question, per Stack Overflow guidelines.